# Right Speaker not working Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04, laptop, speakers

Sound only coming from left speaker on laptop. I checked balance in GUI and alsamixer. In settings GUI it is exactly in the middle, in alsamixer both left and right are at 100. When I slide balance all the way to the right in settings, I lose sound entirely. When I keep it balanced and run the sound test, only the "Front Left" test sound comes through. I have this laptop dual-booted with Win 10 and just installed Ubuntu tonight. Win 10 has stereo sound. When I plug in headphones, the sound works as expected, both channels clear. It only has an issue with integrated right speaker on Ubuntu specifically. Any ideas where to troubleshoot from here?

Comment: I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

For one user there was no sound using pulseaudio. I had to remove .config/pulse directory (rm -rf .config/pulse) and restart pulseaudio deamon (sudo killall pulseaudio).

The above commands partially restored my sound, meaning that now the left speaker was working while the right one was not (for the other user everything worked as it should). Next, I installed pavucontrol and ran the pavucontrol. In the interface I just changed the gain for the speakers and the right channel was working again.

I am not sure what the problem might be, but this worked for me. Previous solution by enabling pipewire made things only worse for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Restart alsa works for me. Left and right speaker now works.

restart alsa with this command:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

If rebooting makes problem return, a crontab simple script for above command may be usefull.